# runtime error: file size unexpectedly exceeded zip64 limit

Tags: python, numpy

after running the following line of code,

```
np.savez(os.path.join(data_path,'file.npz'),Arrays)
```

I am getting `'RuntimeError file size unexpectedly exceeded zip64 limit`'

I have tried adding `force_zip64=True` as following but I am getting the same error:

```
np.savez(os.path.join(data_path,'file.npz'),force_zip64=True,Arrays)
```

Comment: What is the size of the file you are trying to create?

Comment: The error message indicates that it's already using zip64, why do you think forcing it would make a difference?

Comment: @eatmeimadanish when the file.npz reaches to 8.2 GB it returns this error message, Memory available on my machine is 64 GB.

Comment: @Barmar according to suggestions in this link, I used force_zip https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10776

Comment: Tell us about `Arrays` - number of arrays and their sizes.

Comment: @hpaulj I have 9 arrays and the size of arrays is between 1 to 30 Mb, the thing which is not clear to me the memory usage before running this command is 50% but after running this command it reaches to 98%(but swap size is free 70%) and then it returns Runtime Error

Comment: This looks like a limit to the `zip` archive mechanism, rather than memory and array sizes themselves.  Could you save the 9 arrays individually with `save`?

Comment: Zip64 has a theoretical file size limit of 16 exabytes. Which is effectively unlimited. However, the actual file size limit depends on the OS and filesystem. Crucial details you omitted. You should also specify which version of Python and Numpy you are using.

Comment: @KurtisRader Hi, thanks for your reply, OS is Ubuntu 18.04 with ext4 filesystem. Python version is 3.6 and the numpy version is 1.16.1. downrading to other version of numpy returns other types of error. any clue?

Comment: The zip module has no difficulty creating a zip file > 8 GiB; even on 32-bit Ubuntu. You're likely running into https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10776 or a similar issue with Numpy.

Comment: @KurtisRader according to the link you provided, I already did set  force_zip64=True and nothing changed. there is a question which is not clear to me, all of those arrays that I feed as input to np.savez() function are less than 10 MB but while the code is running the file.npz size goes to 8 GB. any clue?